# Validation for xxx-xxx-xxxx or (xxx)xxx-xxxx

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Whats the regex for

```
xxx-xxx-xxxx
or
(xxx)xxx-xxxx
```

I can create regex for the first one with

```
/^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

but how to add rule in this so it can also handle the second one?

Comment: Why not strip out everything that isn't a number, then check the length?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this: -

```
/^(?:\(\d{3}\)|\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm no guru but this should do the trick;

```
/^(\d{3}\-)?(\(\d{3}\))?\d{3}\-\d{4}$/
```

Comment: Precisely, this will also match - `xxx-(xxx)xxx-xxxx`, but again it's not specified what OP don't want to match. So, it's a valid solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^(\(\d{3}\))|(\d{3}-)\d{3}-\d{4}$/
```